# Soundcloud Javascript API: can't disable visual player

Tags: soundcloud

I'm having an issue with the Soundcloud Javscript API where I cannot seem to turn off the visual player (the artwork image shows as a background) in order to have the artwork image show as a small square image to the left of the player instead of as the background image.

I've tried everything in setting the parameters but nothing seems to disable the visual player (I can however change the height, turn off comments, etc...). Here's my code:

```
SC.get("/users/"+slt.userId+"/tracks", {limit: slt.tracks, offset : ((trackPage-1)*slt.tracks), visual: false, show_artwork: false }, function(tracks){
        for (var i = 0; i < slt.tracks; i++) {
            if ( tracks[i] !== undefined ) {        
                var track = tracks[i];
                }
                    SC.oEmbed(track.uri, { maxheight: slt.maxheight, show_comments: slt.show_comments, show_user: true, show_artwork: false, visual: false}, document.getElementById(("slt-track-"+_trackCount)));
            }
        }
    });
```

Any help would be truly appreciated!!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here but I finally figured it out:

I guess SoundCloud has not yet implemented a visual option to their API as of yet so I had edit the iframe string I got back from the oEmbed method so that the code looks like the following now:

```
                SC.oEmbed(track.uri, { maxheight: slt.maxheight, show_comments: slt.show_comments, show_user: true}, function(oembed){
                        jQuery("#player-id").html(oembed.html.replace('visual=true&',''));
                    });
```

This basically just removed the visual parameter in the iframe string which changes the SoundCloud player from a visual one to the normal HTML5 one.

I hope that helps anyone else who had trouble with the Javascript SDK API!